# Woocommerce filter item results on order page based on meta value

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to know if its possible if we could filter the results from the Add items field when adding new order. I have a custom post meta `branch_location` on the product post and want to only show specific products which contains a meta value of `cdo`.

here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I3xH.jpg

thanks!